# Signature key was not found - IdentityServer4, OpenSSL and ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openssl, identityserver4

I'm getting the following response when using Postman to send a GET request with bearer token to my API:

> Status: 401 Unauthorized
>
> WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

My solution includes an authorization server running IdentityServer4 and a RESTful API built in ASP.NET Core 2.2

The authorization server is configured with a test resource, client and user. It responds to requests for tokens using the test user's credentials.  I receive back the authorization token no problem.

My API has a single values controller decorated with the [Authorize] action filter.  Before adding the filter it responded as expected to GET requests.  Afterward is responds with a 401 status when no token is sent, but the problem is I'm also getting a 401 when I include the token in the request header.  I get the above response saying the signature key was not found.

I have also configured IdentityServer4 to log to the console, but I'm not actually seeing any logged messages after the 401 response.

Solutions offered on stackoverflow to similar scenarios have not solved my issue.  I've confirmed that the configured API name matches the client_id in my token request header, in this case "logbookapi".  I'm sending the token using the Authorization header key, and adding the token as the value "Bearer ".

```
// API - Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<ILogbookRepository, LogbookRepository>();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ApiName = "logbookapi",
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddCors();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:6200/logbook")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}


// Authorization Server - Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\logbookapi.pfx", "password"))
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
            .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList());

        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}


// Authorization Server - in-memory config
public static class InMemoryConfiguration
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ApiResource("logbookapi", "Logbook API")
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "w4lkr", // unique name for this in-memory client
                ClientSecrets = new[]
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256()) // client secret hashed
                },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials, // allow authorization via username/password and authorization token
                AllowedScopes = new[] // which scopes this client is allowed to use
                {
                    "logbookapi"
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestUser> Users()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "mail@curtwalker.com",
                Password = "password"
            }
        };
    }
}


// API - values controller
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

The desired result is for the API to respond with

```
{ "value1", "value2" }
```

as shown in the values controller.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar issue and I'm not having much luck finding a solution.